# Where's the error in this Scala code?

Tags: scala, aws-lambda

I am brand new to Scala and trying to experiment with AWS Lambda functions. I am following this article: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/writing-aws-lambda-functions-in-scala/

I created a build.sbt file with this code.

```
javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.8", "-target", "1.8", "-Xlint")

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    name := "lambda-demo",
    version := "1.0",
    scalaVersion := "2.11.4",
    retrieveManaged := true,
    libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "aws-lambda-java-core" % "1.0.0",
    libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "aws-lambda-java-events" % "1.0.0"
  )

mergeStrategy in assembly <
   {
    case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
    case x => MergeStrategy.first
   }
}
```

However, when I try to compile I get one of several errors, depending on how I try to fix it. One such error is this:

```
/build.sbt:14: error: value < is not a member of sbt.TaskKey[sbt.File]
mergeStrategy in assembly <
```

This is pretty much totally foreign to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have a loose angle bracket on this line:

```
mergeStrategy in assembly <
```

and that the syntax you are looking for is this:

```
mergeStrategy in assembly := {
    case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
    case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

It might also be:

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := { /* Same case statements */ }
```

[Here](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) is a link to the sbt-assembly project you are using to create the JAR.  There are more examples there.

---

Edit for your comment:

The merge strategy needs to be part of the `root.settings`:

```
javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.8", "-target", "1.8", "-Xlint")

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    name := "lambda-demo",
    version := "1.0",
    scalaVersion := "2.11.4",
    retrieveManaged := true,
    libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "aws-lambda-java-core" % "1.0.0",
    libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "aws-lambda-java-events" % "1.0.0",
    assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
      case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
      case x => MergeStrategy.first
    }
  )
```

Comment: That fixed that error, but now it is complaining about a missing semicolon on the last line.  build.sbt]:18: ';' expected but eof found. I will have a look at the link you included. Thx very much.

Comment: @DannyEllisJr. I edited my answer wit the complete `build.sbt` file you need

Comment: That solved this problem. Blowing up elsewhere, but that should be a different question.  Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Cool.  Its too bad that the tutorial you are following has invalid code snippets.